# How to prove that $\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\ge2, \text{ }x\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$?

Tags: inequality

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\ge2, \text{ }x\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$$

Equality seems to be when *x* = 1

I have managed to show that the derivative is 0 at x = 1, and that this is a minimum (by the second derivative test), but I am stuck on how to show that this is the *only* minimum.

If $f(x)$ is defined as the LHS, then we have
$$\begin{array}{l}f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1+2}{x+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}=\sqrt{x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\\
f^{\prime}\left(x\right)=\frac{1-\frac{2}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}{2\sqrt{x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}}}-\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=0\\
\frac{1-\frac{2}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}{2\sqrt{x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2}\\
\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2\left(\left(x+1\right)^2-2\right)=2\left(x+1\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}}\\
x\left(x+1+2\sqrt{x}\right)^2\left(\left(x+1\right)^2-2\right)^2=2\left(x+1\right)^4\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}\right)\end{array}$$

At this point the computations become unrealistic without enlisting the help of wolfram alpha to expand everything. I did this, and was left with a massive polynomial which had the root x = 1.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zgFC.png) is a graph

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried or where you are getting stuck so that we can better help you. Otherwise it is quite probable your question will attract downvotes or be closed.

Comment: Suggest you include the derivative, along with details about how you tried to show it has only one critical point at $x=1.$ [This will show you tried something, and maybe keep your question from getting closed.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice followed by an application of AM-GM inequality:

$\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2(x+1)}}\ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2(x+1)}}}=2$. Thus the minimum value is $2$ and this is achieved when $x = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can take the first derivative of this function

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}}\;+\;\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}$$

we get

$$\frac{x^2+2x-1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2}$$

We then want to find the critical number by letting the first derivative be $0$, and we solve for x

$$\frac{x^2+2x-1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)^2}=0$$
$$x=1$$

Next, we can use the first derivative again to see whether or not, at x=1, the function is a maximum or minimum. You can do this by using the first derivative test. After that, the only critical number is $1$, which tells us that when $x = 1$, it has to be a global minimum.

Sub $x=1$ into the original function, we obtain $2$, and since when $x=1$ is a global minimum,

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+1}\ge 2$$

Comment: oh you updated the question, my bad I didn't catch up with the update so TLDR, because 1 is the only critical number it has to be a global extrema

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I managed to follow your steps, but I think a key detail is missing. How do we show that x = 1 is the ONLY solution to the derivative = 0 equation?

Comment: by proving with contradiction but i can't really show that with such a small panel here.